# javascript in button click event?

Tags: asp.net

i place the onClick event in asp buttons. but it is showing error like

Too many characters in character literal

my code is

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
    onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');" />
```

actually my requirement is when i click on the button i want to display some message and when we press ok  then it is redirect to another page is it possible

thank you

Comment: ya it is working, but i want to redirect to another page i write code in button click event 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the OnClientClick method, OnClick is the server side event. e.g.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure');" />
```

This code produces a message box which if cancelled, prevents the server-side event from being fired. If you click 'OK' to the message box the server event is fired as usual and you can then do your redirect as necessary.

Comment: ya it is working, but i want to redirect to another page i write code in button click event 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("yahoo.com");
    }
but it is giving error

Comment: Hi, try changing it to the full address with the http bit i.e. `Response.Redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");`

Answer (score 2):

Change onClick to OnClientClick

Comment: OnClientClick is the client side click event.